# Problem with Ctrl-Left/Right bindings in oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh

For some reason I am unable to bind Ctrl-Left Arrow and Ctrl-Right Arrow to move between words in ZSH after installing oh-my-zsh on my MacBook Pro.

In iTerm2 I have my keybindings configured to "Send Escape Sequence" [1;5D and [1;5C, which worked before installing oh-my-zsh.

I also tried uncommenting

```
bindkey '^[^[[C' emacs-forward-word
bindkey '^[^[[D' emacs-backward-word
```

in ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/key-bindings.zsh, also to no avail. In both scenarios, hitting Ctrl-Left/Right just sends "5D" and "5C" to the screen.

TLDR: Has anyone gotten Ctrl-Left and Ctrl-Right to move between words when using oh-my-zsh?

Answer (score 8):

Change your bindkey lines to:

```
bindkey '^[[1;5C' emacs-forward-word
bindkey '^[[1;5D' emacs-backward-word
```

Answer (score 7):

Press `^v(Ctrl-v)` or `cat` in the `zsh shell`, followed by the `key-combinations(Ctrl+left)` whichever you wanna use, to get the corresponding bindkey value. Use this output in the command. It varies from system to system depending on the terminal driver, etc.

In my case `Ctrl-left` was `^[O5D`. Hence, `bindkey '^[O5D' backward-word`

If you wanna go one step ahead, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8645267/2538943 provides the idea to generalize zsh key bindings, with the help of the cmd `autoload zkbd ; zkbd`. Once done, add the following line, `source ~/.zkbd/$TERM-${${DISPLAY:t}:-$VENDOR-$OSTYPE}` to your .zshrc. From now on, you may write  it like `[[ -n ${key[Left]} ]] && bindkey "${key[Left]}" backward-char`. In this way, you can copy the same .zshrc to different machines too.

Additional info:
Peter Stephenson says `...the function keys on your keyboard... It depends a good deal on how your windowing system or terminal driver handles them...`
Hence it is better to validate all those key binds before running any such script, though it might not vary in most of the cases.

For detailed understanding of key bindings for zsh, check this guide. http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html.

If you wanna know how a key pressed is displayed, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work/116630#116630

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me:

```
bindkey "[C" emacs-forward-word   #control left
bindkey "[D" backward-word        #control right
```

In fact, I pressed <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> between the "" and that did the magic.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this because I was having similar issues on a macbook using external keyboard.

Turns out ctrl+Left and ctrl+Right are set as **Keyboard shortcuts for mission control**.

Disabling this on the system fixed my issue

Adding

```
bindkey '\e\e[C' forward-word
bindkey '\e\e[D' backward-word
```

Enabled alt+right and alt+left to do the same thing

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me. I couldn't figure out why my terminal didn't output anything at all for CTRL+<arrow>, but it was of course swallowed, so iTerm2 never got the key event at all.

Answer (score 0):

So you have your terminal emulator sending one CSI sequence (ESC+`[`+`1;5C`) for the key, but you've told your shell with the `bindkey` command to watch the terminal input for a *different* CSI sequence (ESC+ESC+`[`+`C`), and you are wondering why this doesn't work?

It doesn't work for the very obvious reason.